# Is there a difference between User.select('*') vs User.all in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Is there a significant difference betweeb the following active record queries in Rails:

```
User.select('*')

User.all
```

mainly in terms of load on DB, results and performance?

**UPDATE**:
Based on MrYoshiji's response below the most significant difference is that 
User.select('*') returns an active record result set whereas User.all returns an array of items. Significant if you require built-in active record methods.

Comment: There is no significant difference between the two, but the `User.all` option is the most used because it lets ActiveRecord determine what to select from the model's table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. The generated SQL query would be almost the same.

In Postgres, using `User.select('*')` you would get a query with `SELECT * FROM users`.
Using `User.all` you would get a query with `SELECT users.* FROM users`.

Don't know exactly what would happen in MySQL, but I guess it's the same.